# Elasticsearch store field vs _source

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch 1.4.3

I'm building a sort of "reporting" system. And the client can pick and chose which fields they want returned in their result.

In 90% of the cases the client will never pick all the fields, so I figured I can disable _source field in my mapping to save space. But then I learned that

```
GET myIndex/myType/_search/
{
    "fields": ["field1", "field2"]
    ...
}
```

Does not return the fields.

So I assume I have to then use "store": true for each field. From what I read this will be faster for searches, but I guess space wise it will be the same as _source or we still save space?

Comment: I did some testing. Inserted 4 types x 100,000 each = 400,000 per index.

_source: true = 45MB
_source: true, _all: false = 34MB
_source: false = 30MB
_source: false, _all: false = 18MB
_source: false, store: true (all fields) = 39.5MB
_source: false, store: true (all fields), _all:false = 28.5MB

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `_source` field stores the JSON you send to Elasticsearch and you can choose to only return certain fields if needed, which is perfect for your use case. I have never heard that the stored fields will be faster for searches. The `_source` field could be bigger on disk space, but if you have to store every field there is no need to use stored fields over the `_source` field. If you do disable the source field it will mean:

- You won’t be able to do partial updates
- You won’t be able to re-index your data from the JSON in your
  Elasticsearch cluster, you’ll have to re-index from the data source
  (which is usually a lot slower).

Comment: So basically you should use `stored` fields only if you want to keep some fields from the document vs all fields to save some disk space?

Answer (score 16):

By default in elasticsearch, the `_source` (the document one indexed) is stored. This means when you search, you can get the actual document source back. Moreover, elasticsearch will automatically extract `fields/objects` from the `_source` and return them if you explicitly ask for it (as well as possibly use it in other components, like highlighting).

You can specify that a specific field is also stored. This means that the data for that field will be stored **on its own**. Meaning that if you ask for `field1` (which is stored), elasticsearch will identify that its stored, and load it from the index instead of getting it from the `_source` (assuming `_source` is enabled).

When do you want to enable storing specific fields? Most times, you don't. Fetching the `_source` is fast and extracting it is fast as well. If you have very large documents, where the cost of storing the `_source`, or the cost of parsing the `_source` is high, you can explicitly map some fields to be stored instead.

Note, there is a cost of retrieving each stored field. So, for example, if you have a json with 10 fields with reasonable size, and you map all of them as stored, and ask for all of them, this means loading each one (more disk seeks), compared to just loading the `_source` (which is one field, possibly compressed).

**I got this answer on below link answered by shay.banon you can read this whole thread to get good understanding about it.** [enter link description here](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/What-does-it-mean-to-quot-store-quot-a-field-td3514176.html)

Comment: Please do not copy-paste the same answer to multiple questions (http://stackoverflow.com/a/38787655/466738, http://stackoverflow.com/a/38787576/466738). If you think the questions relate to the same thing, flag them to be closed as as duplicates (http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 9):

Clinton Gormley says in the link below

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/j8cfbv-j73g/discussion

- by default ES stores your JSON doc in the _source field, which is
  set to "stored"
- by default, the fields in your JSON doc are set to NOT be "stored"
  (ie stored as a separate field)
- so when ES returns your doc (search or get) it just load the _source
  field and returns that, ie a single disk seek

Some people think that by storing individual fields, it will be faster
than loading the whole JSON doc from the _source field.  What they don't
realise is that each stored field requires a disk seek (10ms each seek!
), and that the sum of those seeks far outweighs the cost of just
sending the _source field.

In other words, it is almost always a false optimization.

Comment: What about the data storage medium where random access is possible? Will source be advantageous in that scenario?

Answer (score 6):

Enabling `_source` will store the entire JSON document in the index while `store` will only store individual fields that are marked so. So using `store` might be better than using `_source` if you want to save disk space.

Comment: Testing it... By disabling source I saved about 1GB of space (including replica). Using store: true on all fields it seems I'm still saving same space. I suppose in this case stored field is accessed directly from indexed data?

Answer (score 5):

As a reference for *ES 7.3*, the answer becomes clearer. **DO NOT** try to optimize before you have strong testing reasons **UNDER REALISTIC PRODUCTION CONDITIONS**.

I might just quote from the [_source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html):

> Users often disable the `_source` field without thinking about the
>   consequences, and then live to regret it.  If the `_source` field isn't
>   available then a number of features are not supported:
>
> - The `update`, `update_by_query`,
>     and `reindex` APIs.
> - On the fly highlighting.
> - The ability to reindex from one Elasticsearch index to another, either
>     to change mappings or analysis, or to upgrade an index to a new major
>     version.
> - The ability to debug queries or aggregations by viewing the original
>     document used at index time.
> - Potentially in the future, the ability to repair index corruption
>     automatically.
>
> TIP: If disk space is a concern, rather increase the
>   compression level instead of disabling the `_source`.

Besides there are not obvious advantages using [`stored_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html#mapping-store) as you might have thought of.

> If you only want to retrieve the value of a single field or of a few fields, instead of the whole _source, then this can be achieved with [`source filtering`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering).

Comment: This makes it even more harder for me to understand the use case for `stored` fields and the reasons ES even added it!