# Elasticsearch: “fields” only contain dates

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to build an application and I am struggling to understand how "fields" and "_source" works.
When I view my documents in Kibana, I noticed that most fields are not contained in the "fields"-element (json). Actually only the dates appear in this element. All the other fields are only contained in the _source. Also I did not used arrays to store the dates. In the source they are displayed normally and in the fields they are displayed in brackets.
I added all the fields the same way via the Java High Level REST Client. They all are simply added via an XContentBuilder. What might be the reason they are not all contained the same way in "fields"?

Comment: by default ES stores your JSON doc in the _source field, which is set to "stored",by default, the fields in your JSON doc are set to NOT be "stored" (ie stored as a separate field) and when ES returns your doc (search or get) it just load the _source field and returns that, ie a single disk seek. Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678296/elasticsearch-store-field-vs-source

Comment: can you try refreshing the mapping ?

Comment: @redhatvicky I refreshed it multiple times.

Comment: @redhatvicky I also tried to drop and recreate my whole index multiple times. Same behaviour. At the moment I do not know if this is expected or if it is a bug. It do not causes any problems when doing searches. I just try to understand why it behaves like this (I use ES for my master thesis, so an deep understanding is important for me).

Comment: @redhatvicky But what might be the reason, that dates are stored? I do not set this on any place. Like I understand not storing fields, do not cause any problems. Here [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-stored-fields.html] it says:

"The stored_fields parameter is about fields that are explicitly marked as stored in the mapping, which is off by default and generally not recommended. Use source filtering instead to select subsets of the original source document to be returned."

Then why are dates automatically added to an list (brackets) and stored?

Comment: JSON doesn’t have a date datatype, so dates in Elasticsearch can either be:
strings containing formatted dates, e.g. "2015-01-01" or "2015/01/01 12:10:30" or 
a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch or an integer representing seconds-since-the-epoch. Moreover Dates will always be rendered as strings, even if they were initially supplied as a long in the JSON document.

Comment: The below source link provides more context about the date type : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html