# Elasticsearch: get multiple specified documents in one request?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and hope to know whether this is possible.

Basically, I have the values in the "code" property for multiple documents. Each document has a unique value in this property. Now I have the codes of multiple documents and hope to retrieve them in one request by supplying multiple codes.

Is this doable in Elasticsearch?

Regards.

**Edit**

This is the mapping of the field:

```
"code" : { "type" : "string", "store": "yes", "index": "not_analyzed"},
```

Two example values of this property:

```
0Qr7EjzE943Q
GsPVbMMbVr4s
```

What is the ES syntax to retrieve the two documents in ONE request?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible. That's sort of what ES does. If you'll post some example data and an example query I'll give you a quick demonstration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you probably don't want `"store":"yes"` in your mapping, unless you have `_source` disabled (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103047/why-do-i-need-storeyes-in-elasticsearch)).

So, I created a simple index like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "code": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

added the two docs with the [bulk API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html):

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"code":"0Qr7EjzE943Q"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"code":"GsPVbMMbVr4s"}
```

There are a number of ways I could retrieve those two documents. The most straightforward, especially since the field isn't analyzed, is probably a with [terms query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html):

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
           "code": [
              "0Qr7EjzE943Q",
              "GsPVbMMbVr4s"
           ]
        }
    }
}
```

both documents are returned:

```
{
   "took": 21,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.04500804,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.04500804,
            "_source": {
               "code": "0Qr7EjzE943Q"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.04500804,
            "_source": {
               "code": "GsPVbMMbVr4s"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/a3e3e4f05753268086a530b06148c4552bfce324

Comment: Thanks for your input. Everything makes sense!

Comment: So you can't get multiplier Documents with Get then

Comment: The Multi search API can use GET and multiple search queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search-api-example