# What is the impact of the _source field in ElasticSearch with regards to large documents (extracted PDF Books, documents etc)?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I have looked at the `_source` field that get each document ingested into Elasticsearch gets. The `_source` field seems to be a `stored` field.

I have a concern with regards to the `_source` field storing all of the fields of my document that I submitted especially since the body of the document that I submit is a *pretty large chunk of text*.

**Question is**

Will having such a large chunk of text as a stored field impact `segment merges` or affect `indexing` in a negative way, with the scenario that the rate of document flow also can be quite large?

Is it a better option to have the content of the `_source` field staged by the feeding process (specifically the body) so that I can perform a re-ingestion on schema changes (which is touted to be the advantage of having that `_source` field).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103047/why-do-i-need-storeyes-in-elasticsearch/17110894#17110894) might also be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The **_source** field is one of those things that differentiate Solr from Elasticsearch. In Elasticsearch, it exists to make the developer's job easier. But it does have the costs and trade-offs. Still, you can turn the field off, and loose those advantages.

On the other hand, Solr is a lot more explicit (verbose) about each step, but you get to choose the trade-offs with more granularity as well.

Under the covers, the indexing and searching is actually remarkably similar, despite very different syntax.

Comment: but what is the cost with regards to indexing that I will have to run into in my case (my documents getting indexed are in the order of a few 10s of MB). Will the cost of segment merges be high since my content does get updated (metadata only) quite frequently. I am considering having the source maintained on the end of the feeding subsystem instead of on ElasticSearch.