# RDMS(postgres) indexing vs elasticsearch indexing

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I am a newbie to the elastic search, why can't i use my current RDMS(postgresql) as my full text searching, as postgres has indexing

What's the difference between `postgres indexing` and `elastic search indexing`.

Comment: That question is obviously too broad. If PostgreSQL full text search does what you need, go for it. To make that question answerable, you should at least describe your exact requirements.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe why elastic search came into existence when we have indexing and full text searching feature in some RDMS(postgres)

Comment: I said "if". Obviously a program like elasticsearch that specializes in search should have more features, else it would be poor stuff indeed. But it is beyond the scope of a SO answer to list and compare all features of two programs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539476/what-is-the-difference-between-an-elastic-search-index-and-an-index-in-a-relatio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between an elastic search index and an index in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539476/what-is-the-difference-between-an-elastic-search-index-and-an-index-in-a-relatio)